# Interpolating variables in jekyll/liquid with jekyll-assets

Tags: ruby, jekyll, liquid, templating

I have a list of articles in my data and one of the fields is a link to an image. I'm using `jeykll-assets`, and I would like to load the images using the `asset_path`.  However, the following isn't working:

```
{% for article in site.data.press %}
  <div class="press-item">

    <div class="press-image">
      <div class="centerit"></div>

      <a href="{{ article.url }}" target="_blank">
        <img src="{% asset_path article.logo %}" />
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="press-excerpt">
      <a href="{{ article.url }}" target="_blank">
        <p>{{ article.title }}</p>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="date">{{ article.date }}</div>
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Specifically `<img src="{% asset_path article.logo %}" />` because it doesn't load article.logo dynamically.  What's the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use brackets like this : `<img src="{% asset_path {{ article.logo }} %}" />`

See https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-assets#liquid-variables

Comment: Thanks. FYI, the docs got me there, but I needed to put single quotes around it like: <img src="{% asset_path '{{ article.logo }}' %}" />